# handling HTTP status code with URLSession and Combine

Tags: swift, urlsession, combine

I'm trying to handle the responses that arrive from a `DataTaskPublisher` reading its response status code.

When status code is greater than 299, I'd like to return a `ServiceError` type as Failure. In every examples that I've seen I've used `.mapError` and `.catch`... in this specific case, from a `.flatMap`, I really don't know how to handle the publisher response to return the Error instead of the `TResponse`...

```
    return URLSession.DataTaskPublisher(request: urlRequest, session: .shared)
        .mapError{error in return ServiceError.request}
        .flatMap{ data, response -> AnyPublisher<TResponse, ServiceError> in

            if let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse,
                (200...299).contains(httpResponse.statusCode){

                return Just(data)
                    .decode(type: TResponse.self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
                    .mapError{error in return ServiceError.decode}
                    .eraseToAnyPublisher()
            }else{
                //???? HOW TO HANDLE THE ERROR?
            }
        }
        .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I correctly understood your goal, you need something like

```
}else{
    return Fail(error: ServiceError.badServiceReply)
              .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

Simple example:

```
URLSession.shared
    .dataTaskPublisher(for: URL(string: "https://www.google.com")!)
    .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
    .flatMap { _ in
        Fail(error: URLError(URLError.unsupportedURL)).eraseToAnyPublisher()
    } //for the sake of the demo
    .replaceError(with: "An error occurred") //this sets Failure to Never
    .assign(to: \.stringValue, on: self)
    .store(in: &cancellableBag)
```

would always assign string *"An error occurred"* due to remap to `Fail` publisher

Answer (score 5):

```
enum ServiceErrors: Error { 
    case internalError(_ statusCode: Int)
    case serverError(_ statusCode: Int)
}
    
return URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: urlRequest)
            .tryMap { data, response in
                guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse,
                    200..<300 ~= httpResponse.statusCode else {
                        switch (response as! HTTPURLResponse).statusCode {
                        case (400...499):
                            throw ServiceErrors.internalError((response as! HTTPURLResponse).statusCode)
                        default:
                            throw ServiceErrors.serverError((response as! HTTPURLResponse).statusCode)
                        }
                }
                return data
            }
            .mapError { $0 as! ServiceErrors }
            .decode(type: T.self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
            .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
```

**NOTE:** I relied on [this](https://gist.github.com/stinger/7cb1a81facf7f846e3d53f60be34dd1e) link to make my error handler.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `tryMap` here:

```swift
URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: urlRequest)
    .mapError { error in return ServiceError.request }
    .tryMap { (data, response) throws -> TResponse in
        guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse,
              200...299 ~= httpResponse.statusCode else {
                  throw ServiceError.invalidStatusCode((response as? HTTPURLResponse)?.statusCode ?? 0)
              }
        return try JSONDecoder().decode(TResponse.self, from: data)
    }
    .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
    .eraseToAnyPublisher()
```

This will also simplify your code as you don't need do create an extra publisher.

I also made a few other improvements to the original code:

- used `URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: urlRequest)` instead of `URLSession.DataTaskPublisher(request: urlRequest, session: .shared)`
- used the `~=` operator to check the status code
- used a `guard` instead of a `let` as it's more idiomatic